# MVC: 404 route not working properly in production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-status-code-404

I have the following route at the bottom of my global.asax:

```
//404 ERRORS:
routes.MapRoute(
    "404-PageNotFound",
    "{*url}",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "PageNotFound" }
);
```

Which works fine in Visual Studio, but in production I'm getting the IIS error page.

Shouldn't this route catch *any* URL not caught by the others, therefore no 404s from IIS' perspective? Is there anything else I need to do in web.config?

Note: I do *not* want to redirect to a 404-specific URL; rather I am serving up the 404 error page at the requested URL (I believe this is the proper approach from a usability point of view).

**UPDATE**
In my Error controller, I'm setting `Response.StatusCode = 404;`, which seems to   be the issue. When I remove this and deploy to production again, I'm getting my friendly error pages again. However, I believe I *do* need the 404 status in the HTTP header -- for SEO purposes -- so my question now becomes:

**REVISED QUESTION**
How/why is IIS intercepting the response and sending its out-of-the-box 404 error, and how do I prevent this?

**SOLUTION****
Dommer gets the prize for suggesting `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors=true;` which (I think) was necessary. But there were 2 other key details:

- custom errors needs to be *on* in web.config (duh!), and
- the 404 action must have the [HandleErrors] attribute.

**Making it work everywhere**
Since some URLs  may get mapped to routes other than "404-PageNotFound" but containing invalid parameters, and since I don't want to *redirect* to the 404 page, I created this action in my base controller:

```
[HandleError]
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;     
    return View("PageNotFound", SearchUtilities.GetPageNotFoundModel(HttpContext.Request.RawUrl));          
}
```

and in any controller-action that inherits the base, I simply need to call this whenever I catch an invalid route parameter:

```
return NotFound();
```

note: **Not** RedirectToAction()

**Icing on the cake:**
The model I've generated and passed into the view is about feeding the wordy bits of the URL into our search engine, and displaying the top 3 results as suggestions on the friendly 404 page.

Comment: Glad you got this working. It looks pretty good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your request is matching one of your earlier routes and then failing. A possible solution is to try constraining the other routes like this:

```
// This will match too many things, so let's constrain it to those we know are valid
   routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { controller = "Home|OtherController|AnotherController|..." } // regular expression matching all valid controllers
);

//404 ERRORS:
routes.MapRoute(
    "404-PageNotFound",
    "{*url}",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "PageNotFound" }
);
```

If you want a much more comprehensive answer, then look at this: [How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc/2577095#2577095)

**EDIT:**

To get rid of the custom IIS error try changing your error controller to be like this:

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors=true; // add this line
```

MSDN doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx

Comment: Turns out this is not a route-matching problem. Rather, I suspect, it's an IIS7 settings problem. Please see my update in the question.

Comment: I've added a bit which should help.

Comment: note that you mispelled TrySkipIisCustomErrors with one extra "i" in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "account", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );


routes.MapRoute(
                        "404-PageNotFound", // Route name
                        "{*url}", 
                        new { controller = "Error", action = "PageNotFound", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                    );
```

Comment: @Prassanth: The purpose of the 404 route is to catch all unexpected requests, so a wild-card {*url} route-pattern is quite necessary -- {controller}/{action} will not do. BTW: I've discovered more info about my problem, and revised the question.

Comment: I think a DNS setting redirect in IIS is required. Try to set DNS to make the redirection as per the requirement